# Python - getting mean / sum from subset of column using for loop

Tags: python

Let's say I've the following data:

```
Col1, Col2
Label 1, 54
Label 2, 34
Label 3, 98
Label 1, 23
Label 2, 56
Label 3, 233
```

I tried to get the mean value for each labels using a for loop (yes, I know there's an easier way to do this using groupby, but my following for loop is part of a bigger function):

```
for i in ["'Label 1'", "'Label 2'","'Label 3'"]:
    print(i, np.mean(df[df['Col 1'] == i]['Col 2']))
```

However, the output I got instead was:

```
'Label 1', nan
'Label 2', nan
'Label 3', nan
```

I really couldn't understand why my for loop doesn't work, given that the following subset of code works perfectly:

```
input:
np.mean(df[df['Col 1'] == 'Label 1']['Col 2'])
output:
38.5
```

I eventually got around this problem by label encoding my categorical variables, and getting my for loop to refer to a numerical value instead of a string

Nonetheless, can I understand what was wrong with my original code?

Comment: Note how your manual check uses the string ``'Label 1'``, but your loop uses the string ``"'Label 1'"``. Remove the outer ``"``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `["'Label 1'", "'Label 2'","'Label 3'"]` for `["Label 1", "Label 2","Label 3"]`

Comment: @user13399233 if this answer helps you solve your issue, please mark it as valid response.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of quotes. in first scenario you are checking col1 with " 'label1' " and there is no value for " 'label1' " in your df, so you get NaN, but in the second scenario, you are checking col with " label1 "(with no quotes) so you get the result.

As @JMA answered you should change `["'Label 1'", "'Label 2'","'Label 3'"]` for `["Label 1", "Label 2","Label 3"]`